# How can i add floating component while creating viewport in ext4.1

Tags: extjs4

How can i add a floating window to the viewport while its getting created.
When i'm trying to add whith

```
viewport.on('add',function(){
//my functionality here
});
```

How can i add???

Any help??

Comment: Question is not easy to understand. Do you wish to create window before or after Viewport is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really add components to a viewport while it's being created, unless you override its internal methods. And what you're doing is adding an event listener for the "add" event, which fires when items are added to a container.

I don't see why you're trying to add a window to a viewport, but you would add it just like any other item.

```
Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport", {
    items: [{
        xtype:  "window",
        width:  400,
        height: 400,
        title:  "My Window"
    }]
});
```

Or just create the window by itself, since it is constrained to the document body anyway.

Remember, you have to call the `show` method on a window before it will render to the document (unless you set `autoShow: true` on the window config).